# No matching provisioning profiles found - NativeScript iOS deploy

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I want to publish an update of my NativeScript app into AppStore. Until yesterday the following steps worked:

- move into app directory (from Terminal)
- execute `tns publish ios`
- enter valid e-mail & password combination

Now I need to do another update, but I keep getting the following error:

```
=== BUILD TARGET HandyApp OF PROJECT HandyApp WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found.

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65
# publish ios
```

I am working under Xcode 7.3. I checked my iPhone Developer certificate in Xcode and in my keychain, it is active and not expired. The Provisioning Profile is shown in Xcode. I ensured to use the certificate that is saved in `apple.developer.com` (by downloading it and replacing the old one in that directory).

I got:

- my .mobileprovision
- my .cer
- my .p12

everything in the same directory.

Still there seems something not to be matching. I just can't figure out what might be running wrong. Does anyone know what else I could try to get it working?

Comment: why dont you try with Xcode It works always!

Comment: Because that is the way NativeScript describes it in their documentation so it should work that way too

Comment: Yeah It should work that way! but are you going to stick to something that eat up your whole day when you know other alternates to perform the same